# Merge multiple insert queries into one

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to simplify the following code using only one insert query?

```
if(isset($_POST['colore'])) {
    $range = array_keys($_POST['colore']); 
    foreach ($range as $key) {
    $colore = $_POST['colore'][$key];
    $s = $_POST['S'][$key];
    $m = $_POST['M'][$key];
    $l = $_POST['L'][$key];
    $xl = $_POST['XL'][$key];
    $xxl = $_POST['XXL'][$key];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO store_product_attributes (`prod_id`, `color`, `size`, `qty`)
    VALUES ('$last_id', '$colore', 's', '$s')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = "INSERT INTO store_product_attributes (`prod_id`, `color`, `size`, `qty`)
    VALUES ('$last_id', '$colore', 'm', '$m')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = "INSERT INTO store_product_attributes (`prod_id`, `color`, `size`, `qty`)
    VALUES ('$last_id', '$colore', 'l', '$l')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = "INSERT INTO store_product_attributes (`prod_id`, `color`, `size`, `qty`)
    VALUES ('$last_id', '$colore', 'xl', '$xl')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = "INSERT INTO store_product_attributes (`prod_id`, `color`, `size`, `qty`)
    VALUES ('$last_id', '$colore', 'xxl', '$xxl')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

}

Comment: Your code is very hard to read. By the way you code could be open for blind SQL injections. Make sure that your variables cannot contain bad SQL code.

Comment: I'd like to order a size M with a color of `'; DROP TABLE store_product_attributes --`.

Answer (score 4):

You can rewrite it like this:

```
$colore = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['colore'][$key]);
$s = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['S'][$key]);
$m = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['M'][$key]);
$l = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['L'][$key]);
$xl = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['XL'][$key]);
$xxl = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['XXL'][$key]);

$sql = "
    INSERT INTO store_product_attributes 
        (`prod_id`, `color`, `size`, `qty`)
     VALUES ('$last_id', '$colore', 's', '$s'),
        ('$last_id', '$colore', 'm', '$m'),
        ('$last_id', '$colore', 'l', '$l'),
        ('$last_id', '$colore', 'xl', '$xl'),
        ('$last_id', '$colore', 'xxl', '$xxl')";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

**Important:**

Make sure to [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) all your values used in the query!

And while you're on this, better switch to [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), because the use of the mysql extension is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

You can try :

```
INSERT INTO store_product_attributes (`prod_id`, `color`, `size`, `qty`)
VALUES ('$last_id', '$colore', 's', '$s'), ('$last_id', '$colore', 'm', '$m'), 
('$last_id', '$colore', 'l', '$l'), ('$last_id', '$colore', 'xl', '$xl'), 
('$last_id', '$colore', 'xxl', '$xxl');
```

But your code is dangerous. SQL injection is very easy with that code, you should learn more about security (type on google : "owasp" or "sql injection")

Comment: Thanks, but I have semplified the code, it was too long and yes I secure the code before insert it

Answer (score 0):

If I get the point right, it should be possible to insert multible values with this schema:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, ...) VALUES (...), (...)
```